# Why do you need to be Brazilian to buy a discounted Brazilian domestic flight ticket?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, brazil, brazilian-citizens

Flight tickets in Brazil - at least low cost ones - are only available for holders of a Brazilian CPF (social security number).

See also http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2033569

Can anyone enlighten us on WHY that is?

Comment: The ticket price for domestic flights could be supported by the government as a service to the citizens. So it makes sense to exclude non citizens.

Comment: It's the same in Ecuador and Peru. I have no idea why and I wonder if the answers you get will be applicable. Great question!

Comment: I guess this is just because they have poorly designed systems. Probably someone decided that demanding a CPF would enhance the security of the website but forgot that foreigners don't have one. Some companies say that when the user chooses a different language then the CPF demand is ignored but I haven't checked to see if this is true.

Comment: @HaLaBi Tickets for domestics flights are not supported by government incentives. The companies have requested the government incentive [but this was denied](http://br.reuters.com/article/domesticNews/idBRSPE97M04Y20130823)

Answer (score 9):

This information is not true. There are no restrictions on foreigners buying tickets in Brazilian airline companies.

I can assure you that, at least in the two largest companies ([TAM](http://www.tam.com.br/) and [GOL](http://www.voegol.com.br/)), any foreigner can buy tickets including low cost. The only thing you need to do is change the country configuration to your counry (U.S. i presume) and buy your tickets without informing a CPF.

Just a funny information. Earlier this year, TAM had problems with the American version of the website and tickets were sold far below prices in the Brazilian market. At the end of the year the company was forced to pay a fine for this error.

Comment: Interesting: The last time I checked that would not work, but now I saw it. Token example: GOL from CXJ to SAO on 15.04.2014 - Indeed, Promocional tariffs will be offered - even to europeans.

Comment: Here in Brazil the airlines are known to have terrible web sites both in usability and reliability. So take it easy that everything will be fine :)

Comment: I have seen first hand that in some cases the prices in the "foreign" version of the website (in USD or EUR) are way higher than the same price in the domestic version (in BRL) — and the domestic version requires entering a CPF. It looks like the airlines are using the (lack of) CPF as a way to price gouge foreigners.